# Я ЛЮБЛЮ АЛЛУ БОРИСОВНУ (?) И (?) КУШАТЬ

Tags: пунктуация

Жанна Агузарова сказала: "Я люблю Аллу Борисовну (?) и (?) кушать!"
Необычно сказала... Как теперь то, что она сказала, правильно записать? Более правильно будет запятую перед "И" поставить? Или же не ставить перед "И" ничего, а вот после - уже поставить, например, тире?

Answer (score 1):

***Я люблю Аллу Борисовну и кушать!***

Постановка знака зависит от того, как и в какой обстановке прозвучала эта фраза, то есть была ли обозначена **пауза в речи**.

1. **При отсутствии паузы** здесь нет знака. В этом  случае мы считаем, что одиночный союз И соединяет однородные дополнения, причем второе дополнение выражено инфинитивом.

Соединение разных по форме и значению слов имеет **эффект неожиданности** и даже комичности, но на это, вероятно, и была рассчитана фраза.

2. **При наличии паузы** на  письме ставится интонационное тире (это более вероятный вариант):

*Я люблю Аллу Борисовну — и кушать! Я люблю Аллу Борисовну и — кушать!*

В этом случае эффект неожиданности обозначен самим автором (паузой в речи и тире на письме).

**Правило Розенталя**: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100

Пункт 3. При указании на внезапность, неожиданность наступления действия или при наличии оттенка противопоставления **перед союзом и**, соединяющим два однородных сказуемых, ставится **тире,** реже — многоточие: Скакун мой призадумался — и прыгнул (Л); Хотел объехать целый свет — и не объехал сотой доли (Гр.);

Реже в этих случаях тире ставится **после союза и**: Так я это всё рассудил и — вдруг совсем решился (Дост.);

Comment: Насколько я помню, дополнение, выраженное инфинитивом, не может выражать действие, относящееся к подлежащему.

Comment: Здесь, как я думаю,  другая ситуация. Вы говорите о предложениях вида: он приказал стрелять (кому-то). Здесь у нас объектный инфинитив в роли дополнения. Я люблю кушать - это составное глагольное сказуемое. Но в приведенном предложении структурная схема другая:  однородная связь двух дополнений.  Я не вижу причины, чтобы  искусственно представлять его неполным по образцу: Я люблю Аллу Борисовну и  (я) люблю кушать. Хотя такая трактовка возможна, но мне она не нравится.  Назывная функция для инфинитива здесь вполне возможна и более естественна.

Comment: Это не объясняет комический эффект такого перечисления. Ну, однородные дополнения, что с того? А здесь он достигается тем, что под видом однородных дополнений нам даётся нечто иное. Наподобие: "...Она принуждена была встать со своего ложа, в негодовании и в папильотках..." (Дост.), где обст-во и дополнение поданы как нечто однородное.

Comment: У нас тоже не совсем обычные дополнения. Читатель после союза И ожидает нечто другое -  например, имя  человека, который тоже входит в число любимых.

Answer (score 0):

**Я люблю Аллу Борисовну и кушать!**

Перед *"и"* или после можно поставить интонационное тире.

***Пояснение:***

> Я люблю Аллу Борисовну и [люблю] кушать!

Здесь **1)** сказуемое *люблю* + дополнение *Аллу Борисовну*; **2)** составное глагольное сказуемое *люблю кушать*.

Предложение *"Я люблю Аллу Борисовну и кушать!"* звучит необычно потому, что *"люблю"* одновременно и первое сказуемое, и часть второго.

Тем не менее формально это предложение с одним подлежащим и двумя сказуемыми, соединёнными сочинительным союз *"и"*. Значит, повода для запятой нет.